# rails "delete - destroy" does not automatically refresh the item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a scaffold which has a delete button.

When i click on the delete button, the item is not refreshed to show it is removed.

the controller has the basic redirect_to in it:

```
  def destroy
    @print = Print.find(params[:id])
    @print.destroy
    redirect_to prints_url, :notice => "Successfully Deleted Print Order."
  end
```

I am suspecting the javascript part that is causing the problem

this is what is listed in my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery-fileupload
//= require_tree .
```

my application.html.erb

```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

What could be the problem?

Edit: the view

```
<%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
              print,
              :method => :delete,
             :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
              :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger',
              :remote => true %>
```

Comment: What does your delete button look like? Are you making sure you set the `:method` to `:delete`?

Comment: Yes. the method is correct. I'll update the information above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `:remote => true`, otherwise the page will not refresh. If you want to delete the item using AJAX and without refreshing the page then you will need to remove the item yourself using Javascript. I would suggest starting by removing `:remote => true` until you really really need to do things asynchrously.

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting at the end of a remote method, which means the response coming back to the page isn't going to help much! Instead you should remove the redirect and add a javascript file with the action name (`destroy.rjs` or `destroy.js.erb` depending on your environment).

The javascript file will then be called at the end of the action and you can add to that file the script required to refresh the div that contains the items that have changed.

Alternatively, don't do this as a javascript link, remove the `:remote => true` and it will be treated as an html request and the redirect will work.